# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch on STI through association

Tags: rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, sti

It's gonna get a bit tricky.

So, I have a forum app consisting of `Section` entities. And the forum also has `Char` entities (who write posts and create topics) and `CharGroup` entities for grouping chars. The sections can be set to private access.

Then I got to access permisions to those private sections. I have an `SectionAccess` class with STI that can be either `Access::Char` or `Access::Group`, providing access to individual chars and char_groups accordingly. They all have a `section_id` field linking them to a section and an `access_id` field, linking to either char or a char_group (and a `type` field for STI of cource).

```
class Access::Char < Access
  belongs_to :char, class_name: '::Char', foreign_key: :access_id 
end

class Access::Group < Access
  belongs_to :group, class_name: 'CharGroup`, foreign_key: :access_id
end
```

Now I'm trying to link those up in the `Section` class.

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :access_chrs, class_name: 'Access::Char'
  has_many :access_chars, class_name: '::Char', through: :access_crhs, source: :char 
  # I need the :chars accociation for something else here 

  has_many :access_grps, class_name: 'Access::Group'
  has_many :access_groups, class_name: 'CharGroup', through: :access_grps, source: :group

  ... 
end
```

And this is where I bump into a problem. The `access_chars` association wotks perfectly fine, allowing to read and write with no problem at all. 
The `access_groups` association works fine on reading (e.g. `section.access_groups` and `section.access_group_ids`) and even building (if I call `section.access_groups.new` I get a new `CharGroup` record), but not for writing. No matter how I try to write on this relation (e.g. `section.access_groups << CharGroup.first`, `section.access_group_ids << CharGroup.first.id`, `section.access_group_ids = [1]` or anything else) it gives me an error `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: ::Char(#45301460) expected, got #<CharGroup...`.

Even if I try to do `section.access_groups.create name: 'Foo'` it creates the CharGroup record, but then raises the error on trying to associate it.

Is there any probable solutions other then redefining the methods I need?

Comment: CharGroup classs associations?